# Apache redirect all traffic to HTTPs except for private IP

Tags: apache-2.2, private-ip

I would like to redirect all incoming traffic to HTTPs except for incoming traffic on private IP (10.*.*.*).  With the following configuration, external traffic is not being redirected to HTTPs.

This VirtualHost for private IP

```
<VirtualHost 10.191.120.232:80>
    ServerName webservice.local
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Default VirtualHost to redirect all traffic to HTTPs

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Added the private IP to hopefully clarify my question.